# Why can't I get the user input to output with the result

Tags: c++, arrays

I am working on this currency project, it is supposed to output how many ways there is to makeup change, 
For example when I input 2 dollars the program should output 293 ways.
I got the program to work but couldn't get the program to print the proper result
for example I want the program to print out

```
There are [the number of ways] ways to make up [user input]
```

but my program doesn't printout the last part [user input]

output of the code below is [when entered 2]

There are 293 ways to make up      // The user input is missing

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int currency[11] = { 10000, 5000, 2000, 1000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5 };
int f20(int n, int j)
{
    int i = 0, t;
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    else
    {
        if (n<5) return 0;
    }
    for (t = 0; t<11; t++)
        if (n >= currency[t] && j >= currency[t])
            i += f20(n - currency[t], currency[t]);
    return i;
}

int main(void){
    int counter;
    float usernum;

    do{
        cout << "Enter Total amount:";
        cin >> usernum;
        usernum = usernum * 100;
        for (counter = 0; counter<11; counter++)
            if (currency[counter] <= usernum)
            {
                printf("There are %d ways to make up  \n\n", f20(usernum, currency[counter]), usernum); break;

            }

    } while (usernum != 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't mix `printf` and `cout`. Just use `cout`. And higher compiler warnings should tell you the problem.

Comment: thanks ooga for the advice

Comment: In the `printf` you need to put `%f` to make the float print out, and also `#include <cstdio>`

Comment: Not only should you avoid `printf` (if `std::cout` doesn't cut it because you need the flexibility of a format string, consider Boost.Format), you should also use `double` by default for floating-point numbers, **not** `float`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help, i took ooga's advice and got rid of printf and inserted cout instead and fixed the problem.

```
cout << "There are " << f20(usernum, currency[counter]) << " ways to make up : " << usernum / 100 << "\n\n"; break;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your if statement. currency[0] equals 10000. If usernum = 2 at first then usernum*100 = 200. Now, is 10000 < 200? No, so it evaluate to false, and you answer is not displayed. Rethink you condition.

Comment: the logic is correct you cannot make 200 cents out of 10000 cents obviously thats false

Answer (score 0):

Well don't you think it should be -

```
printf("There are %d ways to make up %d \n\n", f20(usernum, currency[counter]), usernum); break;
```

instead of  -

```
printf("There are %d ways to make up  \n\n", f20(usernum, currency[counter]), usernum); break;
```

You missed a `%d`

Comment: nope doesnt work but thanks anyway i just used plain old cout

Comment: my bad, I didn't notice username is float, it should have been %f(or %l forgot the actual floating point representation :() not %d, but anyway, happy to hear it is solved.